# What GPIOs in NodeMCU are usable

Tags: gpio, pins, nodemcu

I am running out of usable GPIOs in my NodeMCU esp8266 board. I'm making a car. For the car I use L298N motor driver with 4 gear motors. The pins of L298N motor driver is connected as like this,
1.**ENA - D0**
2.**ENB - D1**
3.**IN1 - D2**
4.**IN2 - D3**
5.**IN3 - D4**
6.**IN4 - D5**
and additionally I connected,
1.**D6 - Headlights**
2.**D7 - Reverse lights**
Now I am planning to connect an `Ultrasonic sensor` for the car, if anyone drive the car towards a wall or something accidently. Now I have `D8` pin left in nodeMCU. There are 2 pins in the `Ultrasonic sensor` for the nodeMCU board for receiving and sending signal for ultrasonic sensor bvut there is only one pin left in the nodeMCU board. How can I connect the sensor for the board.

Comment: Could you confirm your question is about a nodemcu based on an ESP8266?

Comment: If you’re using an ESP8266, you could also use D8 (GPIO15) as an additional output, as long it’s not pulled high during boot. If you’re going to use the RX and TX pins as general I/O, you should have the ability to disconnect whatever external hardware is on the Serial pins when flashing the ESP, or rely solely on OTA flashing (upload via Wifi). You should also remove serial port initialization (“serial.begin()”) or any output to the serial port from your code.

Comment: Yeah it's an esp8266 and there are `serial.begin()`. Do I need to remove those